# Blaue Plakette Stuttgart (2019)

Tags: legal, germany, driving, stuttgart

I'm planning to visit Stuttgart. I wasn't in Germany for a year and I'm puzzled by unclear information about the current state of Umweltplakette. The site https://www.blaue-plakette.de/ writes as they were there, but my collegues having relatives in DE has not heard about them, and the site looks a bit strange (it's made as it was official, but it looks it's operated by some private entity).

Is there a Blaue Plakette, or the green one that I currently have should be enough for fine-free visit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Blaue Plakette was proposed by environment organizations, but not (yet?) implemented.

It's complicated:

[image]

You need a green Umweltplakette.

In addition, some diesel cars are not allowed:

- Emissionsklasse Euro 4/IV or below in the whole city
- Emissionsklasse Euro 5/V or below on some streets (starting January 2020)
- additional restrictions might be implemented later

Source: https://www.stuttgart.de/diesel-verkehrsverbot

Answer (score 2):

That certainly is not an official website.

The [actual official website for Stuttgart](https://www.stuttgart.de/umweltzone) says that you can drive with the green Umweltplakette.

> Umweltzonen werden mit einem rechteckigen Schild gekennzeichnet. In besonders gekennzeichneten Umweltzonen ist das Fahren mit einer Umweltplakette dann erlaubt, wenn dies durch ein Zusatzschild ausgewiesen ist. Auf dem Zusatzschild ist die für die freie Fahrt benötigte Plakette abgebildet. In Stuttgart dürfen Sie nur mit einer grünen Umweltplakette fahren.
>
> > Environmental zones are marked with a rectangular sign.  In specially marked environmental zones driving with an environmental badge is then allowed if this is indicated by an additional sign.  The additional plate shows the badge required for the free ride.  In Stuttgart you can only drive with a green environmental badge.

Comment: Such restrictions also exsits in other cities, so you should know the Euro class of your car, especially in the case where the car uses diesel.

Answer (score 1):

Stuttgart hast official information about the "Umweltzone" in the city:
https://www.stuttgart.de/umweltzone

Quote: "Das heißt, dass Ihr Auto eine grüne Umwelt-Plakette benötigt, um in Stuttgart zu fahren und zu parken."

Loose translation: "You need a GREEN Umwelt-Plakette to drive and park within Stuttgart."

So you should be fine.